# 2021 Mathcounts practice competition target #4 question #2

Tags: contest-math

**What is the greatest number of positive consecutive numbers that sum to 400?**

My approach:

> We have terms from : $(x-n)..... x.....(x+n)$
> This would mean the sum of these terms is 
> $(2n+1) * 2x * 1/2  = x(2n+1) = 400$
> $2n+1$ MUST be an odd number, so $x$ is even
> $400 = 20^2  = 2^4 * 5^2$
> The odd multiple is either $5$, with $x$ being 80, or we have $25*16$
> &25*16& would have more terms. Since x is 16, we know we have the range (x-12) = 4 to (x+12) = 28
> Therefore, we have 25 terms as the maximum.

The correct answer is 27, and I don't know how to get that. I considered the possibility of an even amount of terms , but 27 isn't even so that wouldn't matter.  Where did I go wrong / Is the real answer wrong?

PROOF THIS IS NOT AN ONGOING TEST:
[image]

I have the real answer.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? For some kind of copyright reason?

Comment: There is no copyright, this test happened a while ago, and I am just asking for help. I can rename it if you really want.

Comment: @xXACEXx how am I supposed to confirm that? I can show you the results of the test?

Comment: This can't be ongoing because I have the real answer. I also wouldn't have wasted so much time formatting the question.

Comment: To be honest that's pretty ridiculous, the OP clearly had no need to say where the problem came from and there's nothing special with the problem.

Comment: I was just looking for how to solve this so I could use the same process on future tests.

Comment: I removed the downvote. I was only concerned regarding the recent posts of active mathematical contests. Refer to this section https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33328/possible-math-contest-question?cb=1 @Jorge

Comment: @Smartsav10 The official answer is wrong

Answer (score 5):

Let the sum be $\sum_{k=1}^n (x+k)$, where $x\geqslant 0$.
This sum has $n$ positive consecutive terms and equals

$$nx + (1+2+\dots+n) = nx + n(n+1)/2 = \frac n2(2x+n+1)$$

In other words, we need to find the maximal integer $n$ such that for some integral $x\geqslant 0$ we have

$$\frac n2(2x+n+1) = 400 \iff n\big(2x+(n+1)\big) = 800$$

From this, we have that $n$ divides $800$, so $27$ cannot be the answer.
Of course, $n\big(2x+(n+1)\big) > n^2$ so $n$ must be less than $\sqrt{800} \simeq 28.28$, which implies $n\leqslant 28$.

Now, $26$, $27$ and $28$ do not divide $800$, so our first candidate is $25$.
We get

$$25(2x+26) = 800 \implies 2x + 26 = 32 \implies x = 3,$$

which confirms $n=25$ as being the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $400=(x+1)+(x+2)+\cdots+(y-1)+y$, where $y\ge x>0$. Now, we have $400=\frac{x(x+1)}2-\frac{y(y+1)}2$, or equivalently, $800=(x-y)(x+y+1)$. Thus, we wish to find a factorization $800=n\cdot m$ where $m$ and $n$ have different parities, $m>n\ge0$, and which maximizes $n$ (the length of the sum). After some experimentation we see that $n=25$ and $m=32$ is the best possible.